# RegEx Extract Sentence with a Matched Word, without stopping at "Mr.", "Mrs." etc

Tags: regex

I've created a regular expression that can extract sentences containing a matched word.

```
[^.|?|!]*\<friends\>[^.|!|?]*[\"!?:\.]
```

But, it does not apply to cases where there are Mr./Mrs./ Dr. etc in the sentence.

For example:

```
The adventures are great. I don't know whether you know that Dr. Watson and Mr. Holmes are good friends, Ms. Adler.
```

My desired output is:

```
I don't know whether you know that Dr. Watson and Mr. Holmes are good friends, Ms. Adler.
```

How to do this?

Comment: See your regex on Debuggex, I'm not sure you really know what it is matching: https://www.debuggex.com/r/YMtOObNo59HHAv8c

Comment: There are too many exceptions (not just titles but also many abbreviations), hardly you can find a general rule unless you keep a list of them...

Comment: Also, why are you looking for `<friends>` while your input does not contain those `<` and `>` chars? And which language are you using?

Comment: @sp00m \<friends\>  allows searching for words with a hyphen, i make up one: friends-like

Comment: @DanEng Sorry? I don't get it, do you have a preprocessor that transforms your regex? `\<friends\>` in a regex will literally match the string `"<friends>"`...

Comment: @sp00m I add a hyphen between good and friends. And my regex still works. For example: I don't know whether you know that Dr. Watson and Mr. Holmes are good-friends, Ms. Adler.

Answer (score 2):

Through negative lookahead.

```
(?:(?!Mr|Ms|Dr|[.?!]).|Mr\.|Ms\.|Dr\.)*\bfriends\b(?:(?!Mr|Ms|Dr|[.?!]).|Mr\.|Ms\.|Dr\.)*[\"!?:.]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fG1vD4/1)

Comment: I like your answer, way cleaner than mine! It is a disadvantage for engines that don't support negative lookaheads, but Its a clean solution. And works really well.

Comment: You may consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if this really helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this: `(?:(Dr|Mr|Ms)\.|[^.])+` and only return results where group 1 has a match.

Answer (score 1):

```
\.((([^.]*Mr\.)|([^.]*Dr\.)|([^.]*Ms\.))*[^.]*)(?<=friends)
```

This should work, you change the word "friends" to whatever you want to search to in a sentence and you can add further false positive matches with just attaching them right after **|([^.]*Ms.)** in the same style so if you also wanted to ignore M. you would add **|([^.]*M.)** and then the regex would look like this

```
\.((([^.]*Mr\.)|([^.]*Dr\.)|([^.]*Ms\.)|([^.]*M\.))*[^.]*)(?<=friends)
```

Updated solution, its a bit clunky now tho :), its saved in capture group 0

```
\.(((([^.]*Mr\.)|([^.]*Dr\.)|([^.]*Ms\.)|([^.]*M\.))*[^.]*)(?<=friends)((([^.]*Mr\.)|([^.]*Dr\.)|([^.]*Ms\.)|([^.]*M\.))*[^.!?]*))
```

Comment: Using the first regex, the output is: "I don't know whether you know that Dr. Watson and Mr. Holmes are good friends"
How to pass the coma and reaches the end of the sentence, such as ?, ! or a full stop?  Thank you.

Comment: I've got this one: \.((([^.]*Mr\.)|([^.]*Dr\.)|([^.]*Ms\.))*[^.]*)(?<=friends)*\.

Answer (score 1):

If the language you're using supports the PCRE flavor, here could be a first solution:

`((?:[^.?!]|(?<=Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr)\.)*)friends(?1)`

Demo and explanation on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fD4pC2/1)

Comment: My engine doesn't support PCRE. But thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this terrible looking regex:

```
/[a-z](?:(?:(?:drs?|m[rs])\.)|[^.|?|!])*friends(?:(?:(?:drs?|m[rs])\.)|[^.|?|!])*[\"!?:\.]/i
```

You can replace the word `friends` with whatever you want to match.

Notice that it **WILL NOT** match if `friends` is the first word.

You can use this one, which match if `friends` is the first word:

```
/(?:friends|[a-z])?(?:(?:(?:drs?|m[rs])\.)|[^.|?|!])*friends(?:(?:(?:drs?|m[rs])\.)|[^.|?|!])*[\"!?:\.]/i
```

This will match the whitespace right before the sentence begins.

If that is a problem, you can use this:

```
/\s*((?:friends|[a-z])?(?:(?:(?:drs?|m[rs])\.)|[^.|?|!])*friends(?:(?:(?:drs?|m[rs])\.)|[^.|?|!])*[\"!?:\.])/i
```

This will save the whole sentence on `$1`, and will work if `friends` is the first sentence.

All these were tested using Javascript and should work for other flavors.